# How to programmatically authenticate a symfony user for other firewall?

Tags: symfony-2.4

I have a `security.yml` like a:

```
security:  
  firewalls:    
    first_area:  
      pattern: ^/someStr  
      ********  
    second_area:  
      pattern: ^/otherStr  
      ********
```

And I can login to user in the same firewall section, but I can't login to user in the other firewall section. I do it like this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(user, null, 'second_area', userRoles);  
$security->setToken($token);
```

Comment: I solved this problem in a way:  `$this->get('session')->set('_security_NAME-OF-SECTION', serialize($token));` in controller instead `$security->setToken($token);`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/30835493/1668200

Answer (score 1):

Sharing context is more right way than manually storing token in the session: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context