# Set Auth Token manually for different firewall

Tags: symfony

My application has 2 security firewalls

"admin" - used by internal staff

"account" - used by customers.

Previoly I had one action under the account firewall, the action in the controller looks something like this.

```
$user = //get user somehow
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'account', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

With this code above, I was able to "login as" different users, and this was working but not exactly what I wanted.

However, when I move this code to an action inside my the admin firewall, it is instead changing the token for the admin firewall, but I still want it to change the token for the account firewall, is this possible?
(In other words, I only want admin users to have the ability to login as different account users)

I would rather not share the "context" between the firewalls, as I would like someone to be able to be logged into the admin and the account firewalls at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a little hacky, but manually wiriting the token to the session achieved what I wanted

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'account', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('session')->set('_security_account',serialize($token));
// Needed to prepend "_security_" to the firewall name to get "_security_account"
```

Didnt even need to call lines such as

```
//Didnt seem to need to call either of these
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token); //Symfony 2.6+
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token)
```